# Is there a way to get variables from index.js to another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a variable from index.js to another file (api.js). I am running it by using

```
require("/api.js")
```

This works fine I just want to get some data from index.js to the api.js file. Any help is great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used `module.export = "Value"` to get the data I wanted. I did this in index.js and required index.js to get the data

```
const datas = require("./index.js")
const client = datas.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Export a function from *api.js*. Call that function from *index.js* passing the data as arguments.

Comment: Could you show a example of what that would look like? And would my api keep working? I am using express for the api